# I cant download the py4ak lib because of an error regarding the .h file. There is some issue with the C++ build tools that I need help resolving

Tags: python, azure

When I try to pip install the py4ak lib using the following command:

`pip install pyk4a --no-use-pep517 --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-IC:\Program Files\Azure Kinect SDK v1.4.1\sdk\include" --global-option="-LC:\Program Files\Azure Kinect SDK v1.4.1\sdk\windows-desktop\amd64\release\lib"`

I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Abdel Nasser\Documents\azure-kinect> pip install pyk4a --no-use-pep517 --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-IC:\Program Files\Azure Kinect SDK v1.4.1\sdk\include" --global-option="-LC:\Program Files\Azure Kinect SDK v1.4.1\sdk\windows-desktop\amd64\release\lib"
>> 
WARNING: Disabling all use of wheels due to the use of --build-option / --global-option / --install-option.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ywin32 (c:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ywin32 (c:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\lib\site-packages)
Collecting pyk4a
  Using cached pyk4a-1.4.0.tar.gz (23 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pyk4a) (1.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python_version>="3.4" in c:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pyk4a) (0.0.2)
Skipping wheel build for pyk4a, due to binaries being disabled for it.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ywin32 (c:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\lib\site-packages)
Installing collected packages: pyk4a
  Running setup.py install for pyk4a ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pyk4a did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [13 lines of output]
      Automatically detected kinect SDK. Adding include dir: C:\Program Files\Azure Kinect SDK v1.4.1\sdk\include and library dir C:\Program Files\Azure Kinect SDK v1.4.1\sdk\windows-desktop\AMD64\release\lib.
      c:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:771: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        warnings.warn(
      running build_ext
      building 'k4a_module' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\pyk4a
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files\Azure Kinect SDK v1.4.1\sdk\include" "-Ic:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Azure Kinect SDK v1.4.1\sdk\include" "-Ic:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\include" "-Ic:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" /EHsc /Tppyk4a/pyk4a.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\pyk4a/pyk4a.obj
      pyk4a.cpp
      c:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pyk4a

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ywin32 (c:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ywin32 (c:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ywin32 (c:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\lib\site-packages)
```

[Image of C++ build tools that are installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lIHb.jpg)

I am not at all sure how to deal with this:

`c:\users\abdel nasser\desktop\python\python38\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2 [end of output]`
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked these similar issues? [pyconfig.h(59) fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151872/pyconfig-h59-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file), [Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40018405/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory/40810172#40810172) and [Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory](https://codehunter.cc/a/python/cannot-open-include-file-io-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

- To resolve the error, enable the VS compiler to find the header,  by defining the environment variable **INCLUDE** pointing to the path of io.h.
- The location of io.h may change for various versions and environments.

References:
['io.h': No such file or directory during "pip install netifaces"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45904828/io-h-no-such-file-or-directory-during-pip-install-netifaces)